# Error starting distributed load test in non gui mode with JMETER

Tags: jmeter

I get the below error in the `master` machine while running `distributed load test` in non gui mode with `JMETER`. How can I resolve this.

Message in master

```
C:\apache-jmeter-5.4.1\bin>jmeter -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=xx.xx.xx.xx -n -t C:\apache-jmeter-5.4.1\bin\examples\masterslavetest.jmx -l C:\apache-jmeter-5.4.1\bin\examples\result.jtl -R xx.xx.xx.xx
    Creating summariser <summary>
    Created the tree successfully using C:\apache-jmeter-5.4.1\bin\examples\masterslavetest.jmx
    Configuring remote engine: xx.xx.xx.xx
    Using local port: 4000
    Starting distributed test with remote engines: [xx.xx.xx.xx] @ Thu Mar 04 18:53:43 GMT 2021 (1614884023471)
    Error in rconfigure() method java.rmi.MarshalException: error marshalling arguments; nested exception is:
            java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.jmeter.JMeter$ListenToTest
    Remote engines have been started:[]
    The following remote engines have not started:[xx.xx.xx.xx]
    Waiting for possible Shutdown/StopTestNow/HeapDump/ThreadDump message on port 4445
```

Message in slave

```
Using local port: 4000
Created remote object: UnicastServerRef2 [liveRef: [endpoint:[xx.xx.xx.xx:4000,SSLRMIServerSocketFactory(host=lhr4-pegajm-03/xx.xx.xx.xx, keyStoreLocation=rmi_keystore.jks, type=JKS, trustStoreLocation=rmi_keystore.jks, type=JKS, alias=rmi),SSLRMIClientSocketFactory(keyStoreLocation=rmi_keystore.jks, type=JKS, trustStoreLocation=rmi_keystore.jks, type=JKS, alias=rmi)](local),objID:[79aa42b8:177fe8fb2b5:-7fff, 5964228045381296735]]]
```

Below are few additional details.

- `Jmeter` : `5.4.1`
- `Java` : `15`
- Running the tests on windows 10 vms
- Opened `server.rmi.localport`, `client.rmi.localport`, `server.rmi.port`
- Slave doesn't show any logs

Comment: I'm also experiencing this issue. Did yo manage to resolve it or find out why it's not working?